# Programmatically create new content type with fields in Drupal 6

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I want to create a new content type with fields in it using custom PHP module which is present in Drupal 6.

I need to create a new content type using custom PHP, not to add value to a content type.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a module which will create a content type on installation. You can take help of this [documentation on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1044248). A small tutorial is available [here](http://www.dynamiteheads.com/blog/jakub-suchy/how-create-content-types-cck-programatically-drupal-6) too..

Next thing you will want to insert data pro-grammatically & here is the help - [Inserting & Updating Node Programmatically](http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2010/07/16/drupal-6-inserting-updating-nodes-programmatically)

I know it's takes time to start and sometime to make it run but at-least you are willing to start now. So happy coding with Drupal..GOOD LUCK :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CCK module](http://drupal.org/project/cck) to create custom content types in Drupal 6. I'm not sure what you mean by "custom PHP module". CCK should do the trick.

Comment: The OP wants to programmatically create a content type with CCK fields, not do it through the UI

Comment: I hope he wants to create content type by PHP coding like making a module. I have given the answer...